# How to effectively protect routes in combination with react-router and passport on the backend

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, react-redux, passport.js

I have React and Node.js with passport.js on the backend which implements my app auth. My react makes a call to my backend and fetches the authorized user via action reducer. Everything works fine but there is a problem with the route guards. This is how I am protecting the routes if the user is not logged in

if(!this.props.auth) return

The problem is when the user is logged in, if page is refreshed, the code above executes faster than mapStateToProps returns the authorized user and the loggedIn user is redirected to the index page. This is bad user experience. Please help me how to resolve this issue and I would appreciate help and advice.

I think what I need to do is to ensure that store is updated first before DOM is rendered but I am not sure how to do it.

Here is dashboard

```
 class Dashboard extends Component {
 render() {
 if(!this.props.auth) return <Redirect to='/' /> 
 if (!this.props.auth.googleUsername) {
  return <div className='container'> Loading ... </div>;
} else {
  return (
    <div className='container' style={{ margin: '10px 10px' }}>
       {this.props.auth.googleUsername}
    </div>
    );
}
 function mapStateToProps({auth}) {
 return {auth};
}
 export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Dashboard);
```

Here is App.js

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { fetchUser } from './store/actions/index';
import Home from './components/layout/Home';
import Dashboard from './components/layout/Dashboard';

 class App extends Component {

  componentDidMount() {
  this.props.fetchUser();
   } 
    render() {
   return (
    <div>
     <BrowserRouter>
      <div>
        <Header />
        <Switch>
        <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
        <Route path='/dashboard' component={Dashboard} />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
    );
  }
 }
  export default connect(null,{ fetchUser })(App)
```

Action reducer

```
  import axios from 'axios';
  import { FETCH_USER } from './types';
  export const fetchUser =  () => async dispatch => {
  const res = await axios.get('/api/current_user');
  dispatch({ type: FETCH_USER, payload: res.data });
  };
```

Auth Reducer

```
 import { FETCH_USER } from '../actions/types';
 export default function(state = false, action) {
 switch (action.type) {
    case FETCH_USER:
      return action.payload;
  default:
  return state;
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

For those who has this issue, I managed to solve the probable. The issue was that I need to persist redux store across my app. I used a third party library called 'redux-persist'

Here is the set I used in my index.js

```
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import rootReducer from './store/reducers/rootReducer';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import { persistStore, persistReducer } from 'redux-persist';
import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage'; 
import { PersistGate } from 'redux-persist/integration/react';

const persistConfig = {
key: 'root',
storage,
}
   const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer)
   const store = createStore(persistedReducer, applyMiddleware(thunk));
   const persistor = persistStore(store);

  ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
     <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
       <App />
     </PersistGate>
    </Provider>,
   document.getElementById('root'));
```